# open local files in AS3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, file-io

How do i open file and get its content as a ByteArray in AS3. I saw examples, using FileStream & File classes from flex.filesystem, but the doc says it's for AIR only.

Thanks,

Nava

Comment: You've asked a particularly loaded question that'll require a bit more info before it can be answered with more than generalities; there are many ways to do this, but they all depend on the specifics of your use case. What kind of content are you trying to load (e.g., JPG, PNG)? What do you want to do with it after you load it? Are you prompting the user to browse first? So If you haven't already found a solution, post back with an update and we'll see if we can help you get it figured out, because the answers posted so far are sort of part-right, part-not, depending on these missing details.

Comment: I've added a comment on Koen's answer regarding the local file security policy. hth

Comment: i was trying to load a shp binary file, not by browsing, just by name. My problem was, that i didn't put it in the right place... From the other side, that's right that Flex compiler issues security warnings when trying to open a local file. When i implemented it using FileRefrence i could open it and read its data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try either [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) with [content](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoaderDataFormat.html#BINARY) set for binary, or use [URLStream](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLStream.html). What do you need to load ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need to load local binary data file

Comment: no problem. an urlloader shouuld do: var binLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
binLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
binLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, binLoaded);
binLoader.load(new URLRequest('yourfile.bin'));

Comment: I think it was my fault, that the code didn't work. I couldn't find the file, since i didn't put it near Main.mxml, rather near the code source...

Answer (score 4):

You can use a FileReference object to browse for a file and then access the raw bytes via the "data" property on the FileReference when the "complete" event is dispatched.

Answer (score 2):

Flex security prevents simple access to local files.

The most commonly used workaround is having the user select a file, send that to your server, and then downloading that file from your server.

There is access to some local storage (using SharedObject) for storing and reading settings.

hth,

Koen

Comment: I really need this to be local. Is that such a big deal to open a local file on flex? May be it should be an archive?

Comment: If you're only using local files, you can set the compiler to use a local file security policy by adding -use-network=false as a compiler argument in compiler settings. goodluck!

Answer (score 2):

New feature in Flash 10. Last time you can't read the file directly. But now, you can.
http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/20/reading-and-writing-local-files-in-flash-player-10/